# Gradient Color To CGContextRef

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am drawing 4 arcs using CGContextRef.I can fill colour but now i want to set gradient color to that arcs.I did it.it is working fine.Now i want to set different color to each arc.Is there any way to do it?please help me.I am attaching my code and screenshot of that arc.Code :

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGFloat comps[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
CGFloat locs[] = {0,1};
CGGradientRef g = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(space, comps, locs, 2);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat startAngle = 0;
CGFloat endAngle = 90;
CGFloat radius = 100.0;
CGFloat levelWidth = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
    CGContextAddArc(context, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, radius, DEGREES_RADIANS(startAngle), DEGREES_RADIANS(endAngle), NO);
    CGContextAddArc(context, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, radius - levelWidth, DEGREES_RADIANS(endAngle),DEGREES_RADIANS(startAngle), YES);
    startAngle = endAngle;
    endAngle = endAngle + 90;
    CGContextClosePath(context);

}


//CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, g, CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2), 1.0f, CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2), 150, 0);
```

And screen shot : [image]

Comment: gradient color should be on outer (bigger) radius to half of width layer...

Comment: BTW, don't forget to `CGGradientRelease` your `CGGradientRef`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to save the context with `CGContextSaveGState` before you clip, clip and draw the arc, and then restore the context with `CGContextRestoreGState` before drawing the next arc. And you obviously want an array of `CGGradientRef`. Thus:

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGGradientRef g[4];

CGFloat comps0[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
CGFloat locs[] = {0,1};
g[0] = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(space, comps0, locs, 2);

CGFloat comps1[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0};
g[1] = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(space, comps1, locs, 2);

CGFloat comps2[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0};
g[2] = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(space, comps2, locs, 2);

CGFloat comps3[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5,0.0,0.5,1.0};
g[3] = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(space, comps3, locs, 2);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat startAngle = 0;
CGFloat endAngle = 90;
CGFloat radius = 100.0;
CGFloat levelWidth = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
    CGContextAddArc(context, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, radius, DEGREES_RADIANS(startAngle), DEGREES_RADIANS(endAngle), NO);
    CGContextAddArc(context, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, radius - levelWidth, DEGREES_RADIANS(endAngle),DEGREES_RADIANS(startAngle), YES);
    startAngle = endAngle;
    endAngle = endAngle + 90;
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, g[i], CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2), 1.0f, CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2), 150, 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    CGGradientRelease(g[i]);         // don't forget to release the gradient
}
```

[image: radial quadrants]

Comment: @rob what is DEGREES_RADIANS?

Comment: @karthikeyan - Sorry to be confusing. It's a simple macro to convert degrees to radians. 360 degrees = M_PI * 2.0. Thus: `#define DEGREES_RADIANS(degrees) (degrees * M_PI / 180.0)`

Comment: @Rob can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477626/how-to-place-n-number-of-views-horizontally-in-scrollview-using-auto-layout-prog/41477686#41477686