# How to place N number of views Horizontally in scrollview using auto layout programmatically?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, swift3

I want to create N number of views in horizontally in **scrollview**. so I have created One **Temporary View** and i assigned **current view** to that.Then i place constraints based on that.Only one view showing others not showing.
I want Horizontal space between two views.
I am using **VFL** to set a auto layout.
Here is my trying code.

```
func ect() {
        let scrollHeight = self.scrollObj.frame.size.height - 40
        let scrollHeightString = String(describing: scrollHeight)
        print(scrollHeightString)
        var firstTextView = UIView() // this is temporary view
        var columnIndex: CGFloat = 0
        for  _ in 0 ..< 5 {
            let textViewSample = UITextView()
            textViewSample.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            //textViewSample.attributedText = self.htmlString.utf8Data?.attributedString
            textViewSample.isScrollEnabled = false
            textViewSample.tag = Int(columnIndex)
            textViewSample.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            self.scrollObj.addSubview(textViewSample)

            if columnIndex == 0{
//here i am setting first view to left margin.
            self.scrollObj.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[textViewSample]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["textViewSample":textViewSample]))

                //height to textview
                self.scrollObj.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[textViewSample(200)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["textViewSample":textViewSample]))

                //width to textview
                self.scrollObj.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[textViewSample(200)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["textViewSample":textViewSample]))

            }else{

             //setting horizontal space to Temp view and current view   
            self.scrollObj.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[firstTextView]-(10)-[textViewSample]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["textViewSample":textViewSample,"firstTextView":firstTextView]))
                //setting equal width and equal height to second textview based on first
                self.scrollObj.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[firstTextView][textViewSample(==firstTextView)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["textViewSample":textViewSample,"firstTextView":firstTextView]))

            }

            //y position to textview
            self.scrollObj.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(20)-[textViewSample]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["textViewSample":textViewSample]))

            firstTextView = textViewSample//assigning current view to temp view.
            // Increase the current offset
            columnIndex = columnIndex + 1
            }
        self.scrollObj.contentSize = CGSize(width: columnIndex*200, height: columnIndex*200)
        self.scrollObj .setNeedsLayout()
        self.scrollObj.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

This is what my design:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: use a UIStackView if you can

Comment: I need to place a dynamic view, i haven't experience in stack view, that is what i desired this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use constraints, you could do something like this:

```
var previousAnchor = scrollView.leadingAnchor

for _ in 0 ..< 5 {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.backgroundColor = .green
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    scrollView.addSubview(textView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previousAnchor, constant: 10),
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10)
    ])

    previousAnchor = textView.trailingAnchor
}

previousAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Conceptually it's similar to what you have: So, for every text view, set the width to 200, height to 200, space to the prior view to 10. For the first view, it's 10 from the leading edge of the scroll view and for the last view, it's 10 from the trailing edge of the scroll view.

No content size adjustment is needed. No layout related calls. Just add the constraints and you're done.

---

In comments, you say you want the width of the text view to be one third of the scroll view's bounds. Because of the subtleties of constraints with scroll views (see [TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html), where constraints between a scroll view and its subviews are really between the `contentSize` of the scroll view and the subview, not the `frame` of the scroll view), you can't say ⅓ of the scroll view. But you can say ⅓ of the view the scroll view is in, e.g. replace the 200pt width constraint above with:

```
textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0 / 3.0, constant: -13),
```

Likewise, you said you wanted it to be the height of the scroll view bounds less 10 (presumably on both sides). So you could do something like, again replacing the 200pt fixed height constraint with:

```
textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContainer.heightAnchor, constant: -20)
```

Now, because you cannot refer to the `bounds` of the scrollview, what I did was I put the scroll view inside a container view (`scrollViewContainer`), so the bounds of this parent view are the same as that of the scroll view. Now the constraints can refer to this parent view and you'll set these subviews relative to the bounds of the scroll view rather than the `contentSize` of the scroll view.

But when you do that, you see the first three views within the scroll view (and I can scroll to the right to see the rest):

[image]

Comment: very efficient way..Thanks a lot sir!!

Comment: While rotating to landscape its not get adjusted, I don't want to Height scroll, Only horizontal scrolling... i am setting textview height as like below..

override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        scrollHeight = Int(self.scrollObj.bounds.size.height - 20)
        scrollWidth = Int(self.scrollObj.bounds.size.width / 3 - 10)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.scrollObj.layoutIfNeeded()
        
    }

Comment: 200x200 given checking to view appears on not, I want my textview size as top from 10 pixel , bottom from 10 pixel, The textview width is based scrollview width/3

Comment: I want  width size three columns based scrollview width

Comment: The challenge is that, in constraints, references in constraints between scroll views and their subviews are to the `contentSize` of the scroll view, not the scroll view's `frame`/`bounds`. So you have to refer to a parent view of the scroll view. But once you do that, you can have height-20 and width/3-10 (or permutations thereof) that are automatically adjusted when the device rotates. See revised answer above.

Comment: i am facing another problem, i am giving some text to text view, the goal is need to create a column wise text view using text kit framework..Its creating based on text size, While changing rotation the views are resizing but the last textview text is going inside, its not showing some text.I am setting scrolledEnable property to false.Here is my full  code https://codeshare.io/GqoXx5 
Help needed, Thanks in advance..

Comment: i wanted to like this with horizontal scroll, its like a news paper design, but the big image is static size, i want to show big when reach second column, other wise single column enough..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355874/coretext-with-multicolumn-with-image/41373054#41373054 check my question here

Answer (score 1):

In my demo I have done this,

In `ViewDidLoad`

```
        // add scrollView
        let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // scrollview contraints

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


        // add viewContainer
        let viewContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)) // View just after the SV
        viewContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        scrollView.addSubview(viewContainer)

        // viewcontainer contraints

        //viewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        viewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


        // add different subview in scrollview

        var originY:Int = 0
        for  i in 0 ..< 5 {

            let myInnerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: originY , width: Int(scrollView.frame.size.width), height: 100))
            myInnerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            viewContainer.addSubview(myInnerView)


            // for different UI different color
            switch i {
            case 0:
                     myInnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
                break
            case 1:
                myInnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
                break
            case 2:
                myInnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                break
            case 3:
                myInnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                break
            case 4:
                myInnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                break

            default: break

            }

            originY = originY+100+20
        }
```

Add this method

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @the_dahiya..its much helpful, the above answer helping me.

Comment: can you check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355874/coretext-with-multicolumn-with-image/41373054#41373054